# Xamarin MySql connector

Tags: mysql, xamarin

Здравствуйте.
Пишу программу под андроид.
Программа должна подключаться к удаленной БД.

```
 private DataTable GetComments()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder mysqlCSB;
        mysqlCSB = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        mysqlCSB.Server = "127.0.0.1";
        mysqlCSB.Database = "online_quest";
        mysqlCSB.UserID = "root";
        mysqlCSB.Password = "17121989";

        string queryString = @"SELECT id, city_play               
                      FROM   city_play 
                      WHERE  id >= 2";

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = mysqlCSB.ConnectionString;

            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(queryString, con);

            try
            {
                con.Open();

                using (MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        dt.Load(dr);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Написал это в Visual Studio, там подключение MySql Connector сделал, и все отрабатывает. А в Xamarin никак не могу разобраться.
Много гуглил, но никак не могу найти информацию о добавлении Mysql connector в Xamarin.

Comment: Это в принципе плохая практика. Не подключайтесь напрямую к базе данных из мобильных приложений, тем более через Интернет. Выставлять сервер БД для непосредственного доступа из интернета небезопасно.

Рекомендую использовать промежуточный сервер приложений, веб-сервис или что-то подобное для организации работы с базой. [Трёхзвенная архитектура](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Трёхуровневая_архитектура)

Comment: Спасибо.
Обязательно ознакомлюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо.
Методом научного тыка нашел.
В дереве проекта правой кнопкой мыши на папку Ссылки -> Редактировать ссылки.
Там добавляем необходимые библиотеки.